# CakePHP Install Specific Version

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to install CakePHP by referring to their website link: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

I use the below command to install Cake, which it does, but it installs the latest version, i.e, 3.2.0

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name
```

I need to install the version 3.0.0 for a project. Does anybody know how to install cake by specific version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run `composer help create-project` it states that:-

> You can also specify the version with the package name using = or : as separator.

So you can use either of the following commands (similar to installing a package with `require`):-

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:3.0.0 my_app_name
```

Or:-

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app=3.0.0 my_app_name
```

You can also use `*` notation as a wildcard in the version number. So if you want to make sure you get all the most recent bug fixes of the 3.0.x branch:-

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:3.0.* my_app_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app=3.0.0 my_app_name
```

Answer (score 2):

that's  work to me...

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app ProjectName 3.0
```

specify version after project name.

Comment: The OP asked about version 3.0.0, not 3.5.

Comment: Ok, I change my awnser.But, just specify version after project name .. It's work for "any" version

Comment: Well, I never asked for a specific version. Just asked for the syntax

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/cakephp:3.0.0 myapp

I used /cakephp instead of /app

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers - this is already part of the accepted and upvoted answer

Comment: As noted it's actually slightly different. Notice the cakephp/**cakephp** as opposed to cakephp/**app** in the accepted answer. The cake docs describe to use the accepted answer but that wasn't working for me. I was upgrading from 2.1. to 3.0.0. Not sure why but what I posted is what worked for me so future me and others might want to try that approach if the accepted answer doesn't work for them.

Comment: If you upgrade your existing project, why do you use `create-project`?

Comment: Ahh... right. I shouldn't have added that in my comment. I was trying to upgrade which wasn't working and in the process decided to try and create a new project.